# Issues with Subroutine and Code

Tags: vba, excel, loops, subroutine

I am having issues (i have posted before) but i think i am missing something silly. I have a loop that runs though 9 teams in A4-A12 and takes each team name and runs my sub called Dataorangise, this runs a loop for each of the 9 teams but it's not working

What i have is

```
Sub Looproutine()

Dim TeamName As String

For i = 4 To 12

TeamName = Sheets("Parameter").Range("A" & i).Value 'identify the location

    Call Dataorganise(TeamName) ' Call subroutine

Next i

End Sub
```

then the code it is running is

```
Sub Dataorganise(TeamName As String)

Sheets("Data").Range("A:X").copy Destination:=Sheets(TeamName).Range("A1")

Columns("R:R").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$R$1:$R$1048576").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
TeamName

Columns("A:J").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("B:G").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("C:G").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("A1:C1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.copy
Range("E1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("A:D").Select
Range("D1").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("A:C").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    TeamName & "!R1C1:R1048576C3", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=TeamName & "!R1C5", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable7", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

Comment: I think TeamName = Sheets("Parametres").Range("A4" & CStr(i)).Value should be **TeamName = Sheets("Parametres").Range("A" & i).value**

Comment: Thanks for answering. I still get a error on the line "Sheets("Data").Range("A:X").copy Destination:=Sheets("TeamName").Range("A1")"

Comment: Your definition of DataOrganise doesn't take any parameter in input, and you are  calling it with a parameter. You should define Dataorganise with a parameter: `Sub DataOrganise(Teamname as String)`...

Comment: When i define that with my parameter of Teamname, i still get the error in the Dataorganise sub on the line "Sheets("Data").Range("A:X").copy Destination:=Sheets("TeamName").Range("A1")"

Comment: Just like @VincentG mentioned, you need to change Sub Dataoragnise() to **Sub Dataoragnise(TeamName as string)**. Also do you actually have sheet named "TeamName" ? or are you trying to get to the sheet named after TeamName? If latter is the case, lose the "" just type **Sheets(TeamName)**

Comment: I am trying to get it called after the actual teamname so i will remove the "" after, thanks.

Comment: If that's the case, you need to change all of the "TeamName!R1C....." to **TeamName & "!R1C........"**

Comment: Thanks, I can update all those references! the error is still on "Sheets("Data").Range("A:X").copy Destination:=Sheets("TeamName").Range("A1")" which is very confusing

Comment: You did lose the "" in the TeamName, right? and also, the Range("A:X") does not exist, either Columns("A:X") or Range("A1:X50") (I am just putting random numbers in for Range)

Comment: I did remove the "" and made it Teamname & "!R1C.  Does my loop look like its correct? Maybe it's not looping through the 8 team names and thats why?

Comment: Did you try first comment I did. Very on top

Comment: I am guessing you have sheet named **Parameter** that has team names, **Data** where you have all datas, and 9 more sheets with team name...is that correct? Which sheet are you doing all these deleting columns and editing?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The editing should be done in each. The process is the same for each team but i am trying to do it with one bit of code and not 8 times the code

Comment: Try adding **Sheets(TeamName).Activate** right after Sub Dataorganise(TeamName As String). I think this will loop through

Comment: I get a error on that line as if it doesn't know "Teamname" as a range

Comment: are you running macro Looproutine or Dataorganise? Because if you run Dataorganise then remove the sheets(TeamName).Activate. The code will look or sheet named TeamName (Which is Empty) and return error. If you run Looproutine, should run fine

Comment: I am running the looprountine macro

Comment: its running now and copying the data but failing again at the pivot table section "ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        TeamName & "!R1C1:R1048576C3", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=TeamName & "!R1C5", TableName:= _
        "PivotTable7", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub Looproutine()

    Dim TeamName              As String

    For i = 4 To 12

        TeamName = Sheets("Parameter").Range("A" & i).Value    'identify the location

        Call Dataorganise(TeamName)    ' Call subroutine

    Next i

End Sub

Sub Dataorganise(TeamName As String)
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    Dim pt as pivottable
    Set ws = Sheets(TeamName)
    Sheets("Data").Range("A:X").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A1")
    With ws
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Columns("R:R").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=TeamName
        .Range("A:J,L:Q,T:X").EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        .Range("E1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .Columns("A:D").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End With
    Set pt = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                SourceData:="'" & TeamName & "'!" & ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), _
                                Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable( _
                                TableDestination:="'" & TeamName & "'!R1C5", _
                                DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12)
```

Comment: I get a error on the "Range ("A1") part in the pivot table

Comment: Sorry - I just fixed that typo.

Comment: that worked thanks! in the next part i reference the "Pivot table 7" but i see you got rid of that. what do i replace that with?                                                 Sheets(TeamName).Select
    cells(1, 5).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields( _
        "Variable A")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

Comment: I've added a `pt` variable. Use that in place of `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7")`